# Django - Apache: get extended key usage field from x509 client certificate

Tags: python, django, ssl

I am using apache with mod_wsgi to run a django application that mutually authenticates (SSL) with a client.
 I am getting the certificate Common Name using this configuration:

```
SSLUserName SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData
```

I have set the option in the Django backend to explicitly create the user when a non-existing user authenticates with his certificate.

```
class MyBacked(RemoteUserBackend):
     create_unknown_user = True
```

I now want to extend the current configuration to let the backend create the user if it doesn't exist and also add it to a precreated group based on a value from the *certificate* *extended key usage* field.

Answer (score 0):

### To get key usage of an SSL certificate in Python use pyOpenSSL package.

Here's the code for loading a certificate into OpenSSL.crypto object

```
c = OpenSSL.crypto 
st_cert = open(<Path to certificate>,'rt').read() #read certificate
cert = c.load_certificate(c.FILETYPE_PEM, st_cert) #load certificate
ext_cnt = cert.get_extension_count() #get no. of extensions
for index in range(0,ext_cnt):
    if cert.get_extension(index).get_short_name == 'keyUsage': #check if extension name is keyUsage
            keyVal = cert.get_extension(index).get_data() #get data associated with keyUsage extension
            break
```

This will return a hexadecimal value.
To check what is the key usage extension OID and syntax refer : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#appendix-A.1

The hexadecimal value can be interpreted as following:
Eg: 03 02 05 A0

The 4th octet is A0 : 1010 0000

The 3rd octet indicates how many bits are to eliminated from right in 4th octet

So the result is : 101

Since the last bit is 1 it indicates that it is compatible with the DER rules.

### 101 indicates : Digital Signature and Key encipherment is set.

- digitalSignature        (0),

  nonRepudiation          (1),  -- recent editions of X.509 have
  -- renamed this bit to contentCommitment

  keyEncipherment         (2),

  dataEncipherment        (3),

  keyAgreement            (4),

  keyCertSign             (5),

  cRLSign                 (6),

  encipherOnly            (7),

  decipherOnly            (8)

Comment: Minor quibble:  This answer is for 'keyUsage' and the question was about 'extendedKeyUsage'.   The first part is mostly the same - except for the string that the extension short name is compared to.